# Git push upstream to origin without creating local branch

Tags: git

I want to sync up my origin with the upstream. Normally I do the following steps,

```
git fetch upsteam
git checkout <branchname>
git merge <branchname> <upstream/branchname>
git push <branchname>
```

The checkout creates local branches which I have no plans to work on at all. I would like to avoid that and therefore want to know if I can push the changes from upstream directly to origin somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the merge (because origin will not change independently you can use the following.

```
git fetch upstream
git push origin refs/remotes/uptstream/branchname:branchname
```

If you need to merge you will not be able to avoid some local interaction.

If it's only the local branch that bothers you, you could try it with a detached head.