# How to push to upstream in Git?

Tags: git, github

I have a project with a few friends in GitLab, and there is of course the master branch, and there are some others too. When I cloned the repository, I created also an upstream with the command `git remote add upstream ...`.

Then, I issued the `git fetch upstream`. Followed by `git checkout upstream/test1`. Now, if I type `git branch -a`, I get an output like this:

```
* (HEAD detached at upstream/test1)
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/test1
  remotes/upstream/master
```

This is all fine, but then I did some changes to the code in my `upstream/test1` branch. I don't want yet to push them to `origin/test1`, but I want to be able to push my changes to `upstream/test1` so that my other friend can see it. But, if I issue the following set of commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Sample message"
```

After the commit I got the message:

```
[detached HEAD 4f20e95] Sample message
 5 files changed, 12 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

And the hash value changes to `4f20e95` in my command prompt. Then if I do `git push`, I get the following error messages:

```
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

How can I push to my upstream branch without actually pushing to origin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push upstream to origin without creating local branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786395/git-push-upstream-to-origin-without-creating-local-branch)

Comment: "HEAD detached" literally means you're not on a branch.

Comment: @EliSadoff I don't think that's a duplicate, since the OP just wants to know how to push to `upstream`, and doesn't necessarily have anything against creating a local branch.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The branch `upstream/test1` is a remote tracking branch, which can't be updated manually. Such branches track branches on remote servers, and are only updated during `git fetch`/`git push`.

Instead, check out a new local branch first:

```
git checkout -b test1 upstream/test1
```

And commit there as usual. Since you have already committed, instead do:

```
git checkout -b test1 4f20e95
```

When you are ready, push to `upstream`:

```
git push upstream test1
```

---

When you do a plain `git push`, Git uses default values for the remote and branch to push based on certain config options. However, if you aren't on a branch (thus getting the `detached HEAD` message), then Git doesn't know what branch to push, thus giving you the error you received.